# Spring Boot logging - Don't log ConstraintViolationExceptions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions

Here's my problem. I call a service method in the controller which is annotated with `@Transactional`. If this is comitted, a `ConstraintViolationException` occurs. I would like to catch it and put it into my own exception. Now I have the problem that I can catch the `TransactionSystemException`, but an error has already been logged. Can I prevent this somehow?

```
public ResponseEntity<T> update(String id, T obj) {
    try {
        return getResponseEntity(service.update(id, obj));
    } catch (TransactionSystemException ex) {
        System.out.println("CATCHED");
        throw new InternalErrorException();
    }
}
```

During my research I found out that I can disable logging for certain packages like

```
logging.level.org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException=OFF
```

or

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.TransactionException=OFF
```

But that didn't help and I don't want to disable logging completely with `logging.level.org.hibernate=OFF`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use @ControllerAdvice.

https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

https://medium.com/@jovannypcg/understanding-springs-controlleradvice-cd96a364033f

Comment: Sorry, I reverted the config and accidentally switched the hibernate logging off again. Now the message appears again.